# PHP Scraping or manual task automation / Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, web-scraping

I need an opinion about what programming language to use to resolve this requirement.

I currently have an application on Laravel 5.5

My client needs me to obtain certain information from a web page (from third parties). It is not strictly scraping. Actually he needs to automate some manual tasks.

Basically, you need to enter a web page every day and follow these steps:

- Complete user and click
- Wait for the page to be reloaded and then complete the password
- Wait for the page to be reloaded and then select a client in a combobox
- Wait for the page to be reloaded and choose a link
- Wait for the page to be reloaded and capture the results of a table

There are cookies involved.

I can do these actions for example by executing some commands in javascript from the chrome console.

```
document.getElementById ('a'). value = "user"
document.getElementById ('abtn'). click ()
document.getElementById ('password'). value = "testpass"
document.getElementById ('bbtn'). click ()
document.getElementById ('client'). value = "test"
document.getElementById ('client'). click ()
```

I have no experience in scraping. I think:

- The ideal would be to be able to automate it from Laravel, but I do not know if it is possible to go through the 5 pages waiting for an answer.
- I researched and there are many alternatives like Node.js or Phantomjs, but I do not know what is recommended.
- Chrome + Puppeteer + Node JS?
- Chrome extension?

Can someone provide me with a simple code where I can perform those 5 steps? Ideally in PHP.

I'm not interested in the detail of how to get the data from a table. What interests me is knowing how to complete a field, click and wait for the next page. And the cookies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to PHP, then it's better that you use some tool in that language.

Take a look to this:
https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/07/07/scrape-web-content-with-php-no-api-no